# How would this class error be handled?

Tags: html, css

I have some dysfunctional code I have inherited, on some embedded web-servers.
Just to verify, in html, a class, cannot have a space in its name is that right?

```
 <p id="SupplyPLR0" class="data percentage">
```

I'm pretty sure about that, but how would this tag be processed? would it simply be 100% error, or would it point to a class named data?

Comment: Your "data" and "percentage" may be two different classes if single then there should not be space

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's right that `class` should `not` have `space` between them, but to declare `multiple` `class` you have to add `space` between class, thus in you `<p>` tag you have defined `2 classes` data and percentage.

```
<p id="SupplyPLR0" class="data percentage">
<!-- Declaration of two classes data and percentage -->
```

Instead of that you can assign hyphens between them,

```
<p id="SupplyPLR0" class="data-percentage"> 
<!-- Declaration of one class data-percentage as hyphen is added and no space-->
```

`Class` can take `hyphens(-)` and `underscore (_)`, but if you separate that using `space` it will take that as declaration of `2 different class`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, CSS class cannot have a space in its name. Your example is however a valid HTML and assigns 2 classes to the `<p>` element: "data" and "percentage".

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out it would have 2 different classes, `data` and `percentage`.

This means you could (if needed) refer to it using the following css:

```
.data {

}
```

or

```
.percentage {

}
```

or, to be even more specific:

```
.data.percentage {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will point to 2 different classes: `data` and `percentage`